# c# short hand formatting of if statement

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I cant seem to think of a neater way to write this

```
 if (isProcessed)
    returnresults = returnresults.FindAll(x => x.DateProcessed == null);
 else 
    returnresults = returnresults.FindAll(x => x.DateProcessed != null);
```

Anyone know of a shorthand way of writing this?

Comment: Why would you want to? You could use `isProcessed ? ... : ...` but that would kill readability. You could also add `isProcessed` as part of the lambda and that would just make each iteration process two statements. It's fine as it is, focus on more serious problems

Comment: Your condition seems backwards.

Comment: its a minor irritant, seeing these two lines almost exactly the same except the condition operator (== and !=)  will be interested to know if there is a short hand way of writing that to avoid duplication (not a major issue though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your original logic was inverted -- if `isProcessed` is true, you want objects where `.DateProcessed` is *non*-`null`.

```
returnresults = returnresults.FindAll(x => (x.DateProcessed != null) == isProcessed);
```

Comment: knew there would be a way :)  my brain just didnt consider that lol, thank you :)  (think i should maybe have a nap)